# Simple logic help (I hope)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can someone tell me what I'm missing? I can't figure out why the last if (greater than 3) is not being entered. If I have 1 record it's fine, if I have 2 records it's fine, but once I have 3 or more records only the first if (greater than or equal to 1 and not equal to 2) displays. The last if (greater than 3) should show 2 times, but it never gets shown???

What am I missing?

```
%%[
SET @rows = LookupRows("Test_Audience","Subscriber_Key",subscriber_key)
SET @productCount = RowCount(@rows)

FOR @i = 1 TO @productCount DO

    SET @row = Row(@rows, @i)
    SET @PRODUCT = FIELD(@row, "PRODUCT")

    IF @productCount >= 1 AND @productCount != 2 THEN
        IF @i == 1 THEN   
            OUTPUT(ContentBlockbyKey("1_Product"))
        ENDIF

    ELSEIF @productCount == 2 THEN
        OUTPUT(ContentBlockByKey("2_Products"))

    ELSEIF @productCount >= 3 THEN
        IF @i != 1 THEN
            OUTPUT(ContentBlockByKey("Grid"))
        ENDIF
    ENDIF

NEXT @i
]%%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh, it was dropping into the 1st if (greater than or equal to 1 and not equal to 2 each time). Stupid error. I changed it to:

```
%%[
SET @rows = LookupRows("Test_Audience","Subscriber_Key",subscriber_key)
SET @productCount = RowCount(@rows)

FOR @i = 1 TO @productCount DO

    SET @row = Row(@rows, @i)
    SET @PRODUCT = FIELD(@row, "PRODUCT")

    IF @productCount >= 1 AND @i == 1 THEN  
        OUTPUT(ContentBlockbyKey("1_Product"))

    ELSEIF @productCount == 2 THEN
        OUTPUT(ContentBlockByKey("2_Products"))

    ELSEIF @productCount >= 3 THEN
        IF @i != 1 THEN
            OUTPUT(ContentBlockByKey("Grid"))
        ENDIF
    ENDIF

NEXT @i
]%%
```

Comment: Ha ha. I was literally just about to post the above myself when I saw the 'new answers to this question' pop up.